# How can I implement push notifications in Flutter with Pusher Channels? (in android and ios)

Tags: flutter, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, pusher

We're using [pusher_channels_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/pusher_channels_flutter)

for frontend chat system in Flutter.

The chat system's backend is custom developed so we're not using FCM.